# Local Notification Ever Changing Text

Tags: ios, plist, uilocalnotification

I am working on getting local notifications to fire at a time every day (set by the user).  I have done this in the past, but just where it was one static message that would get shown every day.  I would like for it to take the text for the local notification from a plist file I have made with each row being a quote.  Is there a way to fire local notifications, but have it change the text every day?

I have right now:

```
- (IBAction)scheduleNotification {


Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (cls != nil) {

    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    notif.alertBody = @"Today's 5 Minutes With God Study Is Now Available";
    notif.alertAction = @"Ok";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    NSInteger index = [scheduleControl selectedSegmentIndex];
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            break;
        case 1:
            notif.repeatInterval = 0;
            break;

    }

    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Today's Quote!"
                                            forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
    notif.userInfo = userDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
    [self.notifications addObject:notif];
    [notif release];
}


}
```

So, how would I get the alertBody to show a different message each day?

Comment: You would need to add each as a different notification (and reschedule new ones when the app is periodically opened).

Comment: Hey there! Me and my team stuck for hours on the issue. Did you solved it by chance?

Comment: @RoiMulia Unfortunately, local notification can't be scheduled with differing messages without the app being opened and providing some information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new notification every time, for every new message.

Comment: That would be a bit of a pain, and would rely on user to open app every day consistently for it to do what I had in mind.  Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: You can schedule all the notifications for the next X days in one go. Your other option is to use a server with push notifications

Comment: Only time I have used Push Notifications is using the Xtify server and not my own.  Kind of a one-man operation here with an older MacBook Pro.  So, would I need just one long code with a different `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
    [self.notifications addObject:notif];` for every quote I want to schedule?

Comment: Yes, that is, one for every notification

Comment: Why would that be hard? Just a simple for-loop. There's a built-in limit of 64 local notifications. Each time the user opens up the app you can cancel all scheduled notifications and create 64 new ones. Easy.

Comment: That sounds a little odd to me, to create 64 notifications, to fire 1 a day, but have it cancel them all every time user opens the app.  Why would they need to be cancelled each time?  Is it not possible to simply schedule first 64 rows of plist, then once those have gone through, create another 64 notifications for the next ones, without having to cancel notifications every time the app was opened?

Comment: If you app is not opened, there's no way you can create those notifications, your app will be suspended in background.